# generate csv file and save it storage and get save file link for sending in email as attachement in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want generate a csv file of form data when form submit. It will be save in storage. Then get the link of that csv file. Which is send to email as a attachement and then user download it from that link. Using full laravel standard.

I did it like this:

```
if($request->isMethod('post')){
extract($request->all());
$student=array(
    'name'=>request('name'),
    'roll_no'=>request('roll_no'),
    'birth'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime(request('birth'))),
    'school_name'=>request('school_name')
);
$headers = array(
    "Content-type" => "text/csv",
    "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=student-".$student['name'].".csv",
    "Pragma" => "no-cache",
    "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    "Expires" => "0"
);

$columns = array('Name', 'Roll No', 'Birth Date', 'School Name');
$callback = function() use ($student, $columns){
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($file, $columns);
    fputcsv($file, array($student['name'], $student['roll_no'], $student['birth'], $student['school_name']));
    fclose($file);
}
return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
```

}

Comment: You can use
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/store.html

Comment: I want in .csv format